# google map api all infowindows does't show

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-markers

I have a small problem in my JS,

When i hover all my different marks, they don't show i think i understand why but i don't know how to fix it

So there is my code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < latLng.length; i++) {
    var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: latLng[i]
    });

    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString[i]
    });

    mark.addListener('mouseover', function() {
        info.open(map, mark);
        setTimeout(function() {infowindow.close()}, 5000);
    })

    mark.addListener('click', function() {
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(myLatLng);
    });
}
```

`latLng` is an array with items like `{lat: alatitude, long: alongitude}`
and contentString is an array with item like "hello"
it show me all marks but it show the infoWindows only on my last mark

I think it's because my vars are erased by the next vars 
i've tried to use arrays like down but it doesn't works.

```
for (var i = 0; i < latLng.length; i++) {
    var marks = new Array();
    var infos = new Array();

    marks.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: latLng[i]
    }));

    infos.push(new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString[i]
    }));

    marks[i].addListener('mouseover', function() {
        infos[i].open(map, marks[i]);
        setTimeout(function() {infowindow.close()}, 5000);
    })

    marks[i].addListener('click', function() {
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(myLatLng);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i isolated this part in a function and it works :

```
var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: latLng[i]
    });

    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString[i]
    });

    mark.addListener('mouseover', function() {
        info.open(map, mark);
        setTimeout(function() {infowindow.close()}, 5000);
    })

    mark.addListener('click', function() {
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(myLatLng);
    });
```